# Shutting down mysqld

Tags: mysql, linux

I am doing the following in order to shutdown `mysqld` in order to not have an open 3306
port

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

However afterwards when I use `netstat`, `mysqld` is still listening on port 3306 just having a new PID. So what is automatically creating a new process and how do I stop it ? `pkill`ing
the process has the same result.

Comment: What flavor of Linux? Try /etc/init.d/mysqld stop.

Comment: Ubuntu Server 11. Will try, thank you.

Comment: @Perception: Answers as answers, please.

Comment: Thank you, it worked: There was no mysqld but only mysql and doing `/etc/init.d/mysql stop` resulted in being asked to use the `service`

Comment: utility and `sudo service mysql stop` resulted in removing `mysqld`

Answer (score 4):

This done by the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

Edit to be more precise: Note that this command only works on certain machines. This might help, but it is possible your distribution does not support this.

Comment: Sometimes. On some systems.

Comment: In most cases, on most linux systems and probably the one he is using ;-). You don't have to provide an every situation answer. If he doesn't has this we can look further ;-).

Comment: At least indicate this in the answer though! At present it reads as a catch-all answer when it's not.

Answer (score 2):

What distro are you using? Often you'll want to use the start/stop script to shut it down, as there may be a monitoring process that thinks that mysqld should be running, so when it no longer is it starts it back you.

You can also just firewall off port 3306, so only localhost can access it. Might be easier in the long run.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good idea to turn your firewall of unless it is controlled and safe. Seems unnecessary in this case ;-).

Comment: Uh...who said anything about turning off the firewall? I suggested firewalling off the mysqld port.

Comment: And by firewall off, meaning make inaccessible to everything but localhost.